# Postgres: Issue Creating a User

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a database called ADB.

When I create a  new user/role, that user cannot, by default SEE ADB and query against the tables in it.

How can I change that default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you create roles, it may be that your database does not give access rights to the 'public' role (which by default is what new roles belong to). You could grant all rights on the database to public, or make the new role a sub-role of whatever role does have access rights to it.